# What is the most efficient way to return results from recursion?

Tags: c++, recursion

There are 2 possible ways that I am familiar with while returning a boolean/integer value from a recursive function that defines is the operation carried out was a success or not.

1. Using static variables inside the recursive function. Changing values in the recursive calls and then returning the final value once everything is done.
2. Passing the result variable by reference to the recursive function and then manipulating its values in the function and then checking if the value corresponds to the result or not.

   ```
   void Graph::findPath(string from, string to)
   {
       int result = 0;
       if (from == to) cout<<"There is a path!"<<endl;
       else
       {
           findPathHelper(from, to, result);
           if (result) cout<<"There is a path!"<<endl;
           else cout<<"There is not a path!"<<endl;
       }
   }



   void Graph::findPathHelper(string from, string toFind, int &found)
   {
       for (vector<string>::iterator i = adjList[from].begin(); i != adjList[from].end(); ++i)
       {
           if (!(toFind).compare(*i)) 
               {
                   found = 1;
                   break;
               }
           else
               findPathHelper(*i, toFind, found);
       }
   }
   ```

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Thank You

Comment: Why are you using `int` for found? Would `bool` be better. Also pass the strings in as `const string&` - Saves doing the copying

Comment: what is `i` in the code?

Comment: @tobi303 it is the iterator for List

Comment: Perhaps posting code that we can compile - i.e. [MCVE]

Comment: @EdHeal I just wanted to post the code that I am using to show how I am handling recursion as of now.

Comment: It will always be possible to find simple examples suggesting otherwise but, generally speaking, `static` variables can increase difficulty of implementing a recursive function and getting it working correctly.  The first call will need to initialise or reinitialise, all others will need to ensure the value makes sense to the next call, etc.   I would generally either pass a value (by reference or pointer) to be returned or have it as a return value that is used by the caller - which is potentially the same function.

Comment: @Peter 'have it as a return value that is used by the caller - which is potentially the same function.' How to do this so that I don't repeatedly change the values and don't mess up my expected results

Comment: You know you could always use that otherwise useless return type for something (i.e. something other than `void`).

Comment: Declare function as `bool Graph::findPathHelper(const string& from, const string& toFind)` and return `true` or `false` as appropriate.

Comment: @zett42 Whenever I have used this recursion pattern I end up messing my returns and end up with wrong results. Can you point me into the direction where i can better understand how to handle recursion with return values?

Comment: Use debugger to single-step through the code and observe if variables have the expected values.

Comment: @zett42 which debugger to use? I an currently using command line for practice and often use GDB when I get segmentation faults. Is there a better alternative?

Comment: @deadpoolAlready - the point is that you don't do it that way.   Try to ensure that all data passed between two recursive calls of a function do so via the return value or argument list, rather than some other path (like static variables).   The more tricks you use to pass information between two recursive calls, the harder it is to get the function behaving correctly. If a function does not behave correctly, it doesn't matter how "efficient" it is. Generally speaking "efficient but wrong sometimes" is worse than "needs work to make it more efficient, but always produces the right result".

Comment: @Peter Thank you. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a value in the recursive function and use that returned value for checking if it was success or not in subsequent calls.

Using static variable for this purpose may work but it's generally not a good IDEA and many consider it as bad practice.

Look into the below link which explains why we must avoid static or global variables and what kind of problems it could lead to during recursion.

[http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2002/cmsc214/Tutorial/recursion2.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20171217113910/http://www.cs.umd.edu:80/class/fall2002/cmsc214/Tutorial/recursion2.html)

Note: *I do not have enough reputation still to make a comment; and therefore i have posted this as answer.*

Comment: yes got it now; you can return the value i and use that in subsequent calls - this could be one of the options. right? and do you agree with not using static variables in recursion? if not look into that link it'll be of some help.

Comment: Yes I agree to not using static variables in recursion, there's no doubt about that.

Comment: the most efficient way is to return values and to use that; as suggested by many in comments and by me. :)

Comment: Yes I understood it but whenever I use that approach I generally overwrite my return value and mess the output.

Comment: You can use codeblocks - open source for c or c++....and there you will be able to debug;

Comment: Thanks man. Really appreciated. Any resource that will be helpful in understanding this concept better?

Comment: Writing recursive functions is ofcourse an art that comes with practice and the best way to do it in the starting is to trace what happens at each step for which you can use debug option available in almost all compilers nowadays.

Comment: sure; will share a few links where you can look into in my next comment

Comment: https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2002/cmsc214/Tutorial/trace-recursion.html ; http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~calvin/cs110/RECURSION.html ; http://www.danzig.us/cpp/recursion.html ; https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32873/Recursion-made-simple ; http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tail-recursion/ ; https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2002/cmsc214/Tutorial/recursion2.html ; https://www.cs.uic.edu/~jbell/CourseNotes/C_Programming/Functions.html ;  https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-recursion ; http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson16.html

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your implementation to use a return value

```
bool Graph::findPathHelper(const string& from, const string& toFind)
{
    for (vector<string>::iterator i = adjList[from].begin(); i != adjList[from].end(); ++i)
    {
        // I have assumed you comparison was incorrect - i.e. toFind == *i is that you want
        // toFind == *i - The two strings are equal - Thus found
        // or
        // Recurse on *i - Have we found it from recursion
        if (toFind == *i || findPathHelper(*i, toFind))  {
            return true;
        }
    }
    // We have searched everywhere in the recursion and exhausted the list
    // and still have not found it - so return false
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain how 

`if (!(toFind).compare(*i) || findPathHelper(*i, toFind))`

This and 

`return false;`

in the end will really function? I would like to understand but I have been unable to wrap my head around this concept.

Thanks.

Comment: Why did you change to `toFind == *i` from `(!(toFind).compare(*i))` wouldn't this fail?

Comment: I am assuming that you what to check if the two strings are equal if you have found it. Strings have the overloaded operator `==`

Comment: It would be a bit nicer with [range-based for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) (if he compiles on c++11 or above).

Comment: @MarekChocholáček - good point. But I tried to keep the code as same a possible for the poster so as to avoid confusion.

Comment: @EdHeal I see, I am just suggesting. Showing him things that would make his job easier wouldn't hurt, would it?

Comment: @MarekChocholáček - One lesson at a time methinks

Comment: @EdHeal You are right sir. It's in the comments, he can check it if he wants to. Meesa out.